# [Solved] Is clearing_rotation_allowed parameter actually working?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I'm playing with different combinations of recovery behaviors. In some cases, make the robot spin to recover is not an option, so the clearing_rotation_allowed parameters is really helpful. But it doesn't seem to prevent the robot to make in place rotations, when I keep all other recovery-related parameters with default values.

Anyone else show this? Or am I doing something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61798/%5Bsolved%5D-is-clearing_rotation_allowed-parameter-actually-working?/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-06**:
Btw, I created an issue (#38)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a misspelling in the code. Until the fix is released, rename clearing_rotation_allowed to clearing_roatation_allowed should work.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-08-05**:
This is now fixed, just in case anyone else is wondering.